# Scroll to ID broken in main menu

Tags: plugins, menus, jquery, html, links

I've taken over the task to maintain the website of your orchestra. 
Unfortunately the previous maintainer installed quite a lot plugins so it's hard for me to figure out which plugin is actually used for what.

Now I have to figure out, why in our main menu the scroll-to-links are broken but I don't even know where to start.  The html looks correct:

```
<a href="#orchester-neu">Orchester</a>
```

Whereas the link https://www.akkordeonorchester-muenchen.de/#orchester-neu works perfectly fine.

So I looked in the Google Chrome Console which throws Violation Warnings like

> [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 107ms

As far as I know, "*scroll-to*" is done by jQuery "*animate*" function, so this might be a hint on where to start fixing the problem. But the website uses a child-theme of *Simple Key Theme* and as far as a I know, there is no custom code so far. I don't mind adding custom code but as I said, I don'T know where to start looking for the error.

I provided a link to the website above, so please don't hesitate to have a look at the live website yourself. I'd be happy about any hints!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you are having jquery console errors so please fix those then this will work hopefully

Comment: What kind of errors and how do I fix them?

Comment: https://screencast.com/t/EB2CiaUz . These are the errors

Comment: I see the errors, too. But I have no clue how/where to fix them.. That's why I was asking the question :)